# Как сделать правильный редирект для админ-панели WordPress в .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Код меняет URL админки WordPress с https://site.domain/wp-login.php на https://site.domain/kabinet

Как сделать правильный редирект, **не используя site.domain** в RewriteCond?
Что-то же можно придумать через SERVER_NAME.
При смене домена приходится править.
Хотелось бы универсального решения, учитывая http и https.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^kabinet/?$ /wp-login.php?query12345678ddd [R,L]
 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^kabinet/?$ /wp-login.php?query12345678ddd&amp;redirect_to=/wp-admin/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^kabinet/?$ /wp-admin/?query12345678ddd [R,L]
 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)admin-ajax\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)site.domain/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)site.domain/wp-login\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)site.domain/kabinet
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^query12345678ddd
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=postpass
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
RewriteRule ^.*wp-admin/?|^.*wp-login\.php /404 [R,L]
 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^loggedout=true
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wp-login.php?query12345678ddd [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Слово "правильный" и то, что ты  спрашиваешь в разных вопросах - антагонисты. Ибо практически все твои задумки неправильны на корню. Поэтому на них нет ответов (ещё меньше правильных ответов :) )

Comment: Не тратьте время на ерунду. WP обеспечивает полную безопасность, и вот это прятание wp-login.php никому не нужно. Миллионы высоконагруженных и привлекательных для хакеров сайтов не скрывают страницу входа и у них всё в порядке.

Comment: KAGG Design, и с чего вдруг это ерунда? И кто вам сказал, что я от хакеров это делаю? Мне просто нужно изменить URL входа в админку, т.к. сайт для организации, это не блог. А на форму входа URL должны знать только я и ещё 2 человека ;)

Comment: SeVlad, я исхожу из валидаторов, инспекторов, гугл-советов, яндекс-советов и прочего подобного. Значит я то как раз пытаюсь всё сделать правильно?

Comment: Валидаторы тебя заставляют страдать фигнёй, подобной этой? Не верю! Кроме того отчёты валидаторов нужно уметь читать, а не реагировать на каждую строку как кот на валерьянку. (и тут когда к кому-то обращаешься нужно писать не просто ник. а через @ ). Только только тогда человек получит уведомление)

Comment: Что же касается защиты админки, то надо не пытаться скрывать урлы, а просто поставить базовую авторизацию на wp-login.php. Это во сто крат проще, надёжней и безопасней. А своей фигнёй ты рискуешь поломать сайт.

Answer (score -1):

Рекомендую взять серверную переменную SERVER_NAME для редиректа без site.domain в RewriteCond:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Это помогает перенарпавить все запросы с [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) на example.com с кодом 301. Если нужно сделать редирект для http и https, то:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Этот код перенаправляет как http-запросы с [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) на http://example.com, так и https-запросы с [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) на https://example.com.

Comment: Опять ответ из ChatGPT?

Comment: И где тут не прописывается домен? Он аж 4 раза прописан...